# Oracle Refresh Complex MV using union

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a complex materialized view in oracle with the following structure

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_MESSAGES
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT TMPUNION.*, MER.MSG_ID, ORIGINAL_MER.REJECTED_TYPE
FROM
(
SELECT MDI.*, DT1.COLUMN_1
  FROM MASTER_TABLE MDI
INNER JOIN DETAIL_TABLE_1 DT1 ON MDI.ID = DT1.EM_ID
UNION
SELECT MDI.*, DT2.COLUMN_1
  FROM MASTER_TABLE MDI
 INNER JOIN DETAIL_TABLE_2 DT2 ON MDI.ID = DT2.EM_ID
UNION
SELECT MDI.*, DT3.COLUMN_1
  FROM MASTER_TABLE MDI
INNER JOIN DETAIL_TABLE_3 DT3 ON MDI.ID = DT3.EM_ID
) TMPUNION 
  INNER JOIN MESSAGE MER ( ON TMPUNION.MSG_ID = MER.MSG_ID 
                              AND TMPUNION.MSG_TYPE = MER.MSG_TYPE 
                              AND MER.M_MIN_DATE - interval '1' hour <= TMPUNION.MSG_REC_DATE )
LEFT JOIN MESSAGE ORIGINAL_MER ON ( MER.CORREL_ID = ORIGINAL_MER.MSG_ID 
                                        AND MER.DOMAIN = ORIGINAL_MER.DOMAIN 
                                        AND MER.M_MIN_DATE >= ORIGINAL_MER.M_MIN_DATE);
```

This mv can be refreshed only with complete option due to the complex query, is there any way to improve the refreshing ?

Or making 3 mvs (with he corresponding mv logs) one for each query participates of union and then make a view.

Any ideas please to improve my problem ?

Thanks in advance